Getting error when trying to build the solution
Getting below error when trying to build solution.

_Application does not contain a definition for 'Workbooks' and no accessible extension method 'Workbooks' accepting a first argument of
type '_Application' could not be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?) 'Workbook' does not contain a
definition for 'Worksheet' and no accessible extension method
'Worksheets' accepting a first argument of type 'Workbook' could be
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I had restarted my laptop after a mandatory update of the system popup came up. Before that it was working fine.
I have tried to restart the laptop.
I have uninstalled 17.4 and reinstalled VS with 17.8.13 version.
I have also taken a new clone of the repository and tried to build but still getting same error.

Neither of your actions will help there. You need to look at the code and find out what library reference is missing.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example
See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Is your problem solved? Did you install  Office  workload and related NuGet package?

It looks like you intend _Application to refer to the interface in the Excel interop, which has a property Workbooks. A simple explanation would be that you have a using directive for a different namespace that contains an Application interface that does not have a property Workbooks. For example, maybe you have a reference to the Word Interop.
The namespace for the Excel interop is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. The namespace for the Word interop is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
If this is the case then you should remove the using directive for the Word interop if you are not using it, or fully qualify _Application as referring to the interface in the Excel namespace if you are.
Btw, you should include the code that throws the exception in your question and also tag it with the specific technologies as this is specifically to do with Office Interop. (You should do this even if this answer resolves your issue.)

Make sure your Visual Studio is installed with Office Development tools. Rerun the installer and select Modify to verify.

